# How to set multiple error messages with form_set_error?

Tags: forms

I notice I can pass in a message variable to `form_set_error()`.

How can I pass in multiple messages?

I tried calling [form_set_error()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/form_set_error/6) several times, but always the first one is displayed.

So, to sum up I want to show something like this:

- error 1
- error 2
- error 3

Currently, I can only get:

- error 1

Then, once the users correct it, and resubmit it, they get:

- error 2

  if (strpos($form_state["values"]["body"], "

  if (strpos($form_state["values"]["body"], "

If both of these control statements trigger an error, only the first one is shown.
After the user corrects the error, the second error message is shown.

Comment: This is standard Drupal behaviuor

Comment: But when I call form_set_error I do see multiple messages in D6. Infact I'd like to ask how to make FAPI show only the very first message passed in form_set_error.

Comment: AgA he's talking about only a single error message per form element, there can be multiple per form.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would change the code to issue a single call to `form_set_error()` per element:

```
$errors = array();
if (strpos($form_state["values"]["body"], "<h1") === true)
    $error_messages["body"][] = "Blalalabalbal bablalbabla.";

if (strpos($form_state["values"]["body"], "<h3") === false)
    $error_messages["body"][] = "Do this do that balbablalba.";

foreach ($error_messages as $element => $messages) {
    form_set_error($element, theme('item_list', array('items' => messages)));
}
```

Comment: Thanks Janus, I thought of that too. But I really like the bullet points form_set_error generates...I guess I will have to do what you mention though.

Comment: giorgio, `theme('item_list')` generates a bullet point list (an `ul`, or unordered list)

Answer (score 3):

I've created separate function for that:

```
function form_set_error_multiple($name = NULL, $messages = '', $limit_validation_errors = NULL) {
  return form_set_error('extra][items', implode('</li><li>', $messages));
}
```

And then I can call it like that:

```
$errors = [
  'My element error',
  'Another error for the same element',
]

form_set_error_multiple('my_element', $errors);
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you passing the input element name to `form_set_error()`?

According to function name you can pass one message per function call.

Comment: Yes, passing input element. Also provided the code. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this with a "hack":

```
$error_messages = "";
if (strpos($form_state["values"]["body"], "<h1") === true)
   $error_messages .= "Error Message on First Line <br/>";
}
if (strpos($form_state["values"]["body"], "<h3") === false){
   $error_messages .= "Error Message on Another Line <br/>";
}
// next check if there are any errors, and if so, write them to form_set_error
if(strlen($error_messages) > 0){
  form_set_error('',$error_messages);
}
```

This will display all accumulated errors as Drupal message.

Comment: strpos does not return true, pl. correct your second line.